# Docker and JVM, does it create a new JVM installation for each docker instance?

Tags: docker

I'm thinking to install about 8 Java applications with Docker, does Docker create 8 different JVM installations each inside their Docker instances?

If it does, this seems inefficient on space. Also is there any way to work-around and solve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create a JVM image and extend from that image in application specific images the JVM will be on your computer only once, assuming you have the images/containers on the same host of course. In fact, this is a perfect use case for Docker!

Even if you run every app thrice, so you end up with 24 running containers, the JVM will be on your disc only once. The data that your applications write will be on the top file system layer and not affect the layers below it, so you can re-use those for other images at the same time.

If you want, take a look at the JDK-7 image I provide on [Github](https://github.com/Krijger/docker-cookbooks/tree/master/jdk7-oracle), and see for instance how I use that both for a Tomcat image and an Elasticsearch image.

Comment: p.s. I wrote two blog articles that address theses questions, although the one about Tomcat is a bit outdated already. This is no advertisement comment! It's just that I already wrote a lot down there... http://blog.trifork.com/author/quintenk/

Comment: What do you mean by only once? There will be one copy of jvm layer and for each image build on top of this there will be copy as well.